# Add multiple condition in if statement

Tags: php, strlen

I want to add 2 numbers in the strlen command. here is my php code:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dgt']);
if(strlen($name) != "32") {
print "This is not a name.";
} else {
```

It checks if the length is 32. I want it to check if the length is 32 OR 40. how can I do that?

Comment: You shouldn't apply `mysql_real_escape_string()` unless used in a query immediately.

Comment: why you using quotes around 32??... remove the quotes

Comment: Btw, what's so special about a name of length 32 or 40?

Comment: You do not want multiple number in strlen() function (not command).
You want to add multiple condition in if statement. Please adjust your question details according to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [PHP: Logical Operators - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), you want to use either

1. or
2. || (this form has higher precedence)

```
$a or $b    Or  TRUE if either $a or $b is TRUE.
$a || $b    Or  TRUE if either $a or $b is TRUE.
```

So, you could use something like this

```
$len = strlen($name);         // just get the length once and then 
                              // use it to compare however many times....
if (!($len == 32 or $len == 40))
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, don't use `mysql_real_escape_string()`; the old `mysql_` API is deprecated, so consider switching to [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) instead.

Second, you should consider using input filtering; `$_POST['dgt']` may not exist at all, so use [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/filter_input).

Third, you should use numeric values to compare against the output of `strlen()`; although PHP will treat `"32"` as a number, it's better to be explicit.

Lastly, if a name must be either 32 or 40 long, you can simply add the condition:

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dgt', FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW);
if (empty($name) || (strlen($name) != 32 && strlen($name) != 40)) {
    print "This is not a name.";
}
```

Alternatively, use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array):

```
if (empty($name) || !in_array(strlen($name), array(32, 40))) {
    print "This is not a name.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `and` operator "&&" in your conditional, like the code below.

`if(strlen($name) != 32 && strlen($name) != 40)`

If you would like it to check if `name` **is** length 32 or 40 then use the `or` operator "||" like the code below.

`if(strlen($name) == 32 || strlen($name) == 40)`

**user2910265** has a good point, assign the return value of `strlen()` to a variable so that only one call is made, like so.

```
$length = strlen($name);
if(!($length == 32 || $length == 40))
    print "this is not a name.";
} else {
```

Comment: On top of this, put strlen in a variable name so that it only gets called once (instead of twice).  The interpreter will not likely be smart enough to do this for you.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were talking about the second conditional using or. The OP's question is confusing because he says his code is checking if the string is of length 32 when it is actually checking if it is not 32, so I got confused in answering.